# How would you solve this rate of change?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi how would you solve this problem to find the rate of change?

$6$ donuts cost  $7$ dollars and $10$ donuts cost $10$ dollars.

Comment: :( I really have no idea what the question is asking.  Please add more context so your questions can be understood and therefore answerable.

Comment: Thats the only words it says. It says find the slope of 6 donuts that cost $7 and 10 donuts that cost $10..

Comment: Thus you are directly asking us to basically solve one of your homework questions just because you don't want to?  That is not how this site works.

Comment: I was going to say something useful, but with your comment above, I see that you already know that "rate of change" and "slope" are really the same concepts.

Comment: Im not asking you to slove one of my homework questions... Im asking for help since that problem makes no sense..

Comment: If you don't understand the fundamentals of these questions, you should either ask the teacher, or ask about the fundamentals themselves.  We answer within certain context, not including the scenario that we need to teach you something from the ground up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be rephrased: Find the slope of the line passing through the points (6 donuts, \$7) and (10 donuts, \$10).

Which you then solve this formula for $m$:

$$y_2 - y_1 = m(x_2 - x_1)$$

Comment: Thank you for HELPING me:)

Comment: @Hi123 : You're welcome. Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if you think it is the correct one. And welcome to the site.

Comment: Sure will thanks again:)